# why does OpenOffice Calc interpret "0411 08:55" as "411:08:55" in CSV file and what to do about it?

Tags: csv, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

I guess the question says it all. My app outputs a plain text CSV file with month/date shown without separating character. This is plainly visible in Notepad. I even tried putting quotes around it for clarity. Calc, instead of showing what is plainly written there, shows this BS not just in the table but even in the edit cell textbox.

Comment: I think this down to the format of the cells, and auto formatting, it thinks its a number, which it strips off the leading 0.

Comment: and what's `0411` supposed to be?  day+month, or month+year, or year+month, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're importing the CSV to Calc, select this column and change its type to "text", which will prevent Calc to parsing it as a number/datetime.

Then, on the spreadsheet you have enough tools to easily parse it to the value you want. And by "tools" I'm mean formulas like `value`, `mid`, `date`, etc.